# captcha modify six letters

Tags: php, captcha, letters

i have following captcha code:

```
<?php

class CaptchaView extends View
{
    private $fontsDir = 'captcha_resources/fonts/';
    private $backgroundsDir = 'captcha_resources/backgrounds/';
    private static $dirCache = array();

    public function render($controller)
    {
        $code = $controller->viewVars["code"];

        /**
         * The next part is orginnaly written by ted from mastercode.nl and modified for using in this mod.
         **/

        header("content-type:image/png");
        header('Cache-control: no-cache, no-store');

        $width = 100;
        $height = 30;

        $img = imagecreatefrompng(self::backgroundImage());

        // add noise
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
            $horizontal_progress = 0;
            $vertical_pos = rand(1, $height / 2);
            do {
                $horizontal_step_size = floor(rand(1, $width / 5));

                imageline($img, $horizontal_progress, $vertical_pos, ($horizontal_progress += $horizontal_step_size), ($vertical_pos = rand(1, $height)), self::color("tekst"));
            } while ($horizontal_progress < $width);
        }

        $background = imagecolorallocate($img, self::color("bg"), self::color("bg"), self::color("bg"));

        for ($g = 0; $g < 30; $g++) {
            $t = rand(10, 20);
            $t = $t[0];

            $ypos = rand(0, $height);
            $xpos = rand(0, $width);

            $kleur = imagecolorallocate($img, self::color("bgtekst"), self::color("bgtekst"), self::color("bgtekst"));

            imagettftext($img, self::size(), self::move(), $xpos, $ypos, $kleur, self::font(), $t);
        }

        $stukje = $width / (strlen($code) + 3) + 5;

        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($code); $j++) {
            $tek = $code[$j];
            $ypos = rand(23, 27);
            $xpos = $stukje * ($j + 1) - 5;

            $color2 = imagecolorallocate($img, self::color("tekst"), self::color("tekst"), self::color("tekst"));

            imagettftext($img, self::size(), self::move(), $xpos, $ypos, $color2, self::font(), $tek);
        }

        imagepng($img);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
    /**
     * Some functions :)
     * Also orginally written by mastercode.nl
     **/

    /**
     * Function to create a random color
     * @auteur mastercode.nl
     * @param $type string Mode for the color
     * @return int
     **/
    private static function color($type)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case "bg":
                $color = rand(224, 255);
                break;

            case "tekst":
                $color = rand(0, 127);
                break;

            case "bgtekst":
                $color = rand(200, 224);
                break;

            default:
                $color = rand(0, 255);
                break;
        }
        return $color;
    }

    /**
     * Function to ranom the size
     * @auteur mastercode.nl
     * @return int
     **/
    private static function size()
    {
        return rand(18, 22);
    }

    /**
     * Function to random the posistion
     * @auteur mastercode.nl
     * @return int
     **/
    private static function move()
    {
        return rand(-22, 22);
    }

    /**
     * Function to return a ttf file from fonts map
     * @auteur mastercode.nl
     * @return string
     **/
    function randomFileByExt($dir, $ext)
    {
        $f = opendir($dir);

        if (empty(self::$dirCache[$dir])) {
            $ar = array();
            while (($file = @readdir($f)) !== false) {
                if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && substr_compare($file, $ext, -strlen($ext)) == 0) {
                    $ar[] = $file;
                }
            }

            self::$dirCache[$dir] = $ar;
        } else {
            $ar = self::$dirCache[$dir];
        }

        if (count($ar)) {
            $i = rand(0, (count($ar) - 1));
            return $dir . $ar[$i];
        }
    }

    private function backgroundImage()
    {
        return self::randomFileByExt(Config::get("VIEWS_PATH") . $this->backgroundsDir, ".png");
    }

    private function font()
    {
        return self::randomFileByExt(Config::get("VIEWS_PATH") . $this->fontsDir, ".ttf");
    }
}
```

actually it display 4 letters with a disturbed background

i want block some spam bot them i think to modify code to increase security increasing number of letters 
can you tell me how to modify it to display 6 letters instead of 4?

Comment: If bot could recognize 4 letters - it will be able to recognize 6 too. If it is a human being not a program - then it will be able to recognize 6 without issues also.

Comment: Agree with @zerkms. If a bot is able to read the 4 letters. Then the captcha is probably wrong. Try using an existing captcha like reCaptcha.

Comment: i must change with another captcha code?

Comment: the problem is that pages of captcha is located are smarty tpl file It's not simply for me replace this captcha with recaptcha... howeverer thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Best solution is to implement existing Captcha like reCaptcha or so..

- docs : http://code.google.com/intl/en_EN/apis/recaptcha/intro.html
- PHP  : http://code.google.com/intl/en_EN/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html

2) To modify your code to push 6 instead of 4 letters edit part of code like this:

```
$stukje = $width / (strlen($code) + 5) + 5; //instead of  "+3) +5;"
```

should do the trick, but I can't test it, since I don't know in which mod it was used (what CMS, PHP Framework,...)